# Difference between logs collected using Google Workspace Reports API, admin log type "gcp" vs using Cloud Logging API directly?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

As the title says, there seems to be two ways to collect certain GCP audit logs.

1. Using The Google Workspace Admin SDK -- Specifying the "gcp" application name in the call.
2. Using the Google Cloud Logging API

What is the difference in logs collected? I'm still researching but hopefully someone on the google team sees this tag and knows exactly.

Does all of these logs get collected via worksapce admin sdk?
Admin Activity audit logs
Data Access audit logs
System Event audit logs
Policy Denied audit logs

Comment: Seems like only admin audit logs via collected via workspace. Whomever downvoted my post for a genuine question are a waste of space.

Answer (score 1):

The Admin Reports API only reports "OS login" events.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/gcp